# Price prediction based on historic data

Tags: machine-learning

Im new to ML. I'm trying to predict if a new Music Album will exceed X amount of dollars in Sales.
I'm looking to build a model to go only after potential best sellers. I do have historic data for Music Sales from 2010 till 2016. I have many signals:

- Music Genre
- Music Band/Artist name
- Label
- Year released
- Country of origin
- Part of a Series/Volume... etc.
- Sales per month

What type of ML problem is this one?

Comment: Please give your question a better title - half the questions on here could have that title.

Comment: what can the classifier learn from time series data?  certain albulums sold better than others during a certain time of year. certain genre are becoming more popular over time. certain artists are becoming more popular over time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two broad classes of problems in machine learning, classification and regression. As in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/183001), Regression involves estimating or predicting a response (the dependent variable is continuous). Classification is identifying group membership (the dependent variable is discrete).

Your problem is a regression problem, you must try to estimate the real number of sales. You can look [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques) for a similar problem and techniques to solve it.

Comment: As I add more and more variables, is this a Linear regression problem?

Comment: In a linear regression problem, the dependence between the variables is linear. If you add more variables this doesn't mean the dependence becomes linear, however you could add a set of variables that have a linear relation with the dependent variable. You should look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_engineering for a discussion of how to deal with variables (features)

Answer (score 0):

you can use trend data for sales in the past to predict future trends using forecasting.  build an accumulative dataframe of price then use ARIMA to forecast

```
print("Predicted Price pct change")
def plotARMA(df_accumulative,ax,label):
    result=df_accumulative
    result=result.rolling(window=45).mean().dropna()
    mod = sm.tsa.arima.ARIMA(result, order=(2,0,0))
    res = mod.fit()
    # Plot the original series and the forecasted series
    #res.plot_predict(start=0, end=400)
    df_accumulative.plot(ax=ax,label=label)
    res.predict().plot(ax=ax,label=label)

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,20))    
plotARMA(df['close_accum'] ,ax,"Tesla")
plt.legend(fontsize=8)
plt.title("ARMA")
plt.show()
```